# Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel when saving doc on api request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error in the following logic: `[ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 6382d9cca300367cd8fedfbf]`

I have a middleware that retrieves a user doc by an id supplied by cookie data:

```
const getLocalUser = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(res.locals.decodedToken.id)
    .populate("folders")
    .populate("files")
    .exec((err, user) => {
      if (err)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: true, response: err.message });

      if (!user)
        return res.status(409).json({
          error: true,
          response: "No local user tied to account id",
          status: "NO_LOCAL_USER",
        });

      res.locals.user = user;
      next();
    });
};
```

This middleware assigns `res.locals.user` to the document if it is found. In a specific route, I want to push a new folder ObjectId to the user document's folders array:

```
router.post("/", getLocalUser, (req, res) => {
  const folder = new Folder({ ...req.body, owner_ids: [res.locals.user._id] }); // create new folder instance
  res.locals.user.folders.push(folder._id); // push folder _id to user folders
  res.locals.user.markModified("folders"); // mark folders as modified

  res.locals.user.save((err) => {
    // catch "Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: ObjectId"
  });
});
```

The desired behavior should be the new `folder._id` being pushed into `res.locals.user.folders`. If I understand correctly, this error is thrown when attempting to `save()` a doc under the same reference. In this example `res.locals.user` is retrieved per request (different reference for each). Additionally, the requests do not need to be made at the same time in order to trigger this error.

It should be worth noting that this error occurs in a sporadic manner.

I made a series of requests and waited 2 seconds in between each. The first two did not result in the error. The next two did result in an error. The last was also successful.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

(I am aware I can use `.findByIdAndUpdate()` but I want to keep database queries to a minimum. Why make a new retrieval and update request when I can simply save the document)

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for retrieving the user using a middleware?